# How to obtain NIE/ NIF for Spain from India?

Tags: legal, spain, study

I have recently been accepted for Master in Pure and Applied Logic in University of Barcelona. However, while trying to apply for scholarships I am facing some problems. They are listed below,

1. While applying for [General Grant](http://www.ub.edu/web/ub/en/estudis/suport_estudi/beques_ajuts/fitxes/general.html), I observed that for non-EU students like me I need to satisfy the following requirement (see [here](http://www.ub.edu/beques/grausimasters/beca_gral_mecd/02_requisits.html)), "*In the case of being a foreigner with a nationality of a non-EU country, they will be required to have an NIE with a permanent resident status and that they certify that the applicant and / or one of their main supporters of the family unit are workers employed by another person or own during the year prior to the call.*" So my questions are,

   - How do I get an NIE with a permanent resident status **from India before going to Barcelona**?
   - Since neither I nor any of my family members have ever gone to Spain, I was wondering whether there is any other way to meet the requirement "that they certify...prior to the call."
2. While applying for [this scholarship](http://www.vives.org/serveis/ajuts-drac-a-la-mobilitat-a-la-regio-vives/drac-formacio-avancada/), I observed that I need to enter my NIF number in [this form](http://www.vives.org/files/2010/10/Formulari-DRAC-FA2017-18.pdf). So my questions are,

   - How do I get an NIF **from India before going to Barcelona**?

---

**N. B.:** Please note that this is my first question on this site. If there is anything in the post that should be edited, please let me know in the comments before voting to close or downvoting it.

Comment: I don't think you can get it before you have moved (and gotten a permanent address in Spain).

Comment: Additionally, I would guess that you do not actually need it until they are due to start paying you.

Comment: @TomasBy: Sorry but I don't understand your second comment.

Comment: @TomasBy: Note that I can't apply for scholarships if I don't have the numbers (see [this link](http://www.vives.org/files/2010/10/Formulari-DRAC-FA2017-18.pdf) already mentioned in the post). The problem is that without getting scholarships it is impossible for me to go to Barcelona for study.

Comment: I meant that they need the NIF before they can give you money, but not before you apply. But on reading the quoted bit again it does sound like you are supposed to already be in Spain before applying.

Comment: ???? From your link about "General Grant": `Applicants must be Spanish nationals. If not, either the student or one of the main breadwinners in the family unit must be working in Spain.` This makes it very unlikely for you to qualify at least until you are in Spain. Maybe the text that you quote is from somewhere else?

Comment: And for the second one, it seems that it is focused in helping people to "switch" university, but only from one University of the "Vives University Network" to another; the fact that info is only in Catalonian reinforces that impression. Anyway, here is  a list of contacts to request additional info: http://www.vives.org/serveis/ajuts-drac-a-la-mobilitat-a-la-regio-vives/punts-dinformacio-drac/

Comment: I really don't know enough about the system to answer, however I can attest that I got my own NIE printed on my student/intern visa (issued by the consulate in Toronto) by default. I was told by my employer that if I hadn't been automatically issued one with my visa, that I would need to get one within my first few days in Madrid after arriving. So it sounds like you need to ask specifically at your embassy/consulate to make sure that it be issued with your visa.

Comment: @SJuan76: You are right. Thanks.

Comment: @KernelPanic: By student visa did you mean schengen visa?

Comment: @ZachLipton: In which case I would be glad if it were migrated to the site you mention.

Comment: @KernelPanic: In case this question gets closed before I see it again, would you mind to come to [this room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72901/general-chat-with-user-170039) so that I may ask you some questions related to this post but that I fear will unnecessarily make this comment chain lengthy? In that case just give me a ping.

Comment: @TomasBy I suspect very strongly that the reason for the requirement is that the scholarship is available only to those who are either citizens of the EU or residents of Spain.  If I am right about that, they are asking for the number as evidence that the applicant is qualified to apply for the scholarship, which user 170039 is not.

Comment: @user170039 I would like to be able to migrate this very much, but there's no automatic migration path, and the SE people won't let us have one. I've flagged it for a moderator.